# How do I combine two MySQL rows into one and display them in a table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "exercise_results". People put in their results at the beginning and then two months later put in their results to see how much they improved. Their beginning set has the exercise_type_id of "1" and the end set has the exercise_type_id of "2".

I need a way to display this out into a HTML table that looks like this:

[image: Normally I do this using]

a foreach loop, but that's with single rows. I'm having trouble combining two rows into one. I think this may be as simple as some kind of MySQL join? We identify each person by their person_unique_id.

Here are my fields:

```
id | person_unique_id | person_name | exercise_type_id | mile_running_time | bench_press_weight_lbs | squat_weight_lbs | date_of_exercise_performed
```

Sample rows:

```
1 | J123 | John Smith | 1 | 8  | 200 | 300 | 2010-03-20
2 | J123 | John Smith | 2 | 7  | 250 | 400 | 2010-05-20
3 | X584 | Jane Doe   | 1 | 10 | 100 | 200 | 2010-03-20
4 | X584 | Jane Doe   | 2 | 8  | 150 | 220 | 2010-05-20
```

I've tried a few solutions but I'm lost. Any help would be great. Thanks!

EDIT:

In response to the comment below, I would hope for some data like:

```
array  0 => 
array
  'Exercise' => 
    array
      'person_unique_id' => string 'J123'
      'person_name' => string 'John Smith'
      'begin_mile_running_time' => string '8'
      'end_mile_running_time' => string '7'
1 => 
array
  'Exercise' => 
    array
      'person_unique_id' => string 'X584'
      'person_name' => string 'Jane Doe'
      'begin_mile_running_time' => string '10'
      'end_mile_running_time' => string '8'
```

Comment: Is the database fixed? I mean, could you change the tables?

Comment: Not really. There is already a lot of data in the tables being used in a production application.

Comment: You can do this with the query by grouping by id and selecting MAX(IF(exercise_type_id=1,mile_running_time,'')) AS 'Start', MAX(IF(exercise_type_id=2,mile_running_time,'')) AS 'End' etc... can be a bit challenging but I just had to do this sort of rollup.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use **GROUP_CONCAT()** to get a two rows result like this:

```
SELECT person_unique_id, person_name, 
       group_concat( mile_running_time ) AS miles,  
       group_concat( bench_press_weight_lbs ) AS bench, 
       GROUP_CONCAT( squat_weight_lbs ) AS squat
FROM exercise_result
GROUP BY person_unique_id
```

Your result will be like:

```
J123  |  John Smith  |  8,7  |  200,250  |  300,400

X584  |  Jane Doe  |  10,8  |  100,150  |  200,220
```

And then you can use php explode with the result fields to get the results for each type.

Comment: It's nice to have such a simple solution, but it's very restrictive.  This won't work if, say, you have any fields with commas in them (or if MySQL support commas as decimal marks?).  At least use a less common character like the pipe: |

Comment: You can specify the separator you want in your group_concat like this: group_concat(mile_running_time SEPARATOR '#')

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip. Some of the data could possibly have commas, so that is good to know.

Comment: Thank you. GROUP_CONCAT is a super usefully tool that I wish I had know about earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("select ...your data");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query) ) {
    if ($row['exercise_type_id']==1)  
      $exe1[]=$row;
   else  
      $exe2[]=$row;


 }

 print_r($exe1);
 print_r($exe2);
```

from what I've understood

edit:

try this

```
$query = mysql_query("select ...your data");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query) ) {

   $rows[]=array('Exercise'=>$row);


 }

 print_r($rows);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this code create two rows in the HTML table for each person? The first row with their BEGIN data and the second row with their END?

Comment: I tried to get your idea to work but was having difficulties. I think the problem was in my query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the whole table, or whichever rows are interesting to you, sort on person id, compare person id of each row with the next to see if there is a result to print for all columns in your HTML table. If not, jump to the next and leave the fields blank(or some other solution, maybe ignore persons who have not filled in both fields?).

My PHP skills are limited, so no code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ordering on `person_unique_id` then `exercise_type_id`, you can do this.  If you have two rows for everyone, you can leave out the if (only use the else):

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($exercise_results); $i++ )
{
  $first = $exercise_results[$i];
  if( !isset($exercise_results[$i+1])
      || $first['person_unique_id'] != $exercise_results[$i+1]['person_unique_id' ) {
    $second = array(
      'person_name'=>$other['person_name'],
      'mile_running_time' => null // fill in the rest with defaults (like null)
    );
  } else {
    $second = $exercise_results[$i+1];
    $i++; // skip ahead one, since you've already used the second result.
  }
  // perform your normal printing, but use $beginning and $end to get the respective results
}
```